# Using iterators for collision between lists in SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, list, iterator, sprite, sfml

I'm programming a game in SFML 2.0 where there is a collision between two sprite lists. The collision code is pretty correct, but the interators are messed up somehow. I am not knowing how to solve this. Here's my code.

```
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator enemyit = enemy.begin(), next;
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator greenlaserit = greenlaser.begin(), reload;
while(enemyit != enemy.end())
{
    next = enemyit;
    next++;
    while(greenlaserit != greenlaser.end())
    {
        reload = greenlaserit;
        reload++;
        if(enemyit->getGlobalBounds().intersects(greenlaserit->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            enemy.erase(enemyit);
            greenlaser.erase(greenlaserit);
        }
        greenlaserit = reload;
    }
    enemyit = next;
}
```

Here, there are two while loops and what I am doing is I am using the inner loop to check for collision and if collision occurs, I am erasing the enemy iterator. And after doing that, the inner loop will keep looping until the while condition stops being satisfied. It won't enter the outer loop until it finishes that. Problem is, the enemy iterator is being erased in the inner loop and I am not incrementing it until the program goes back to the outer loop. How do I do that so that the enemy iterator is incremented in the inner loop as soon as it is erased. I've tweaked around a lot moving code around inside and outside the loops, adding new variables, still nothing. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to increment the enemyit why don't you just break to the outer while?

```
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator enemyit = enemy.begin(), next;
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator greenlaserit = greenlaser.begin(), reload;
while(enemyit != enemy.end())
{
    next = enemyit;
    next++;
    while(greenlaserit != greenlaser.end())
    {
        reload = greenlaserit;
        reload++;
        if(enemyit->getGlobalBounds().intersects(greenlaserit->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            enemy.erase(enemyit);
            greenlaser.erase(greenlaserit);
            break;
        }
        greenlaserit = reload;
    }
    enemyit = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I swapped the while loops and used Guga00's suggestion of throwing in a `break`. This way, you loop through all the `greenlaserit`s and check each `enemyit`, and, if there's an intersection, erase the `enemyit` and `greenlaserit` and then assign the `next` iterator to `enemyit`, then `break`ing out and assigning the `reload` iterator to `greenlaserit`. If there is no intersection, it just loops normally.

```
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator enemyit = enemy.begin(), next;
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator greenlaserit = greenlaser.begin(), reload;
while(greenlaserit != greenlaser.end())
{
    reload = greenlaser;
    reload++;
    while(enemyit != enemyit.end())
    {
        next = enemyit;
        next++;
        if(enemyit->getGlobalBounds().intersects(greenlaserit->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            enemy.erase(enemyit);
            greenlaser.erase(greenlaserit);
            enemyit = next;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            enemyit = next;
        }
    }
    greenlaserit = reload;
}
```